# no me permite insertar texto por consola en java netbean

Tags: java, consola

[image: me aparece ese error y no deja insertar por consola]

me aparece este error de java en netbean y no lo puedo solucionar

Comment: Que te dice netbeans que error es?

Comment: Creo que "in" es una palabra protegida de Java.
Prueba a usar otro nombre para la variable.

Answer (score -1):

Hola Jonathan te recomiendo poner el código tal cual lo tienes en NetBeans así podremos probar el código y ayudarte más fácilmente. En principio puede ser que lo que te aparece justo donde Scanner no es un error sino una advertencia.
Variable is never read  que significa que no estas usando esa variable o tal vez te falta cerrar alguna llave del main. y cuando ejecutas que mensaje te sale normalmente por consola te indica que puede ser.